# CORS issue with Firebase Cloud Functions and Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send emails to my customers using Firebase Cloud Functions and Sendgrid.
When I send the request to my function in my Angular app I got the following error:
[image: Error message in my console]

I already tried with a proxy conf in my Angular project and it doesn't work.

This is my firebase function:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as sendgrid from "sendgrid";
import * as corsModule from "cors";

exports.httpEmail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () =>
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => {
        if (req.method !== "POST") {
          throw new Error("Only POST requests are accepted");
        }

        const request = client.emptyRequest({
          method: "POST",
          path: "v3/mail/send",
          body: parseBody(req.body)
        });

        return client.API(request);
      })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.body) {
          res.send(response.body);
        } else {
          res.end();
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        throw new Error(err);
      })
  );
});
```

And this is how I call it:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";

sendEmail(emailAddress, content) {
    const url = functionURL;
    const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
   });

   params.set("to", emailAddress);
   params.set("from", "myEmail@gmail.com");
   params.set("content", content);

   return this.http
     .post(url, params, { headers: headers })
     .toPromise()
     .then(res => (this.emailSend = true))
     .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding following in .htaccess file

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
```

Answer (score -1):

I had also tried using proxy but it dont work. whatever method you will implement it may work for some service but not gurantee will work on all. 
This usually happens when your service is not cors enabled. in simple https
you need to enable on your cloud whichever you use but to make it it costs you. you can manually write a code but. you need to write for every service which will be headache for big applications

i use chrome disable security one to test application. you should also try it